Why I get Syntax error when I prepare statement for dropping a Db?
In my code I try to drop a database:
  $connectionString="mysql://...";
  $pdo = new PDO($connectionString);

  ...

  // I intentionally Drop the Db from the user-given db name
  // Details ommited for simplicity
  $testDbName=$_POST['db_name'];
  $stmt = $pdo->prepare("DROP DATABASE :db");
  $stmt->bindValue(":db", $testDbName);
  $stmt->execute();

But I get the following error:
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''test_php_app_1076'' at line 1.ESQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''test_php_app_1076'' at line 1


But if I try this:
  $pdo->query("DROP DATABASE `" . str_replace('`', '``', $testDbName) . "`");

Seem to work fine. Is there a way to make it work using prepared statements?

I can't really understand why you try to use prepared statement for this task. The goal of prepared statements is to prevent users do nasty things in the database.
Also, I know it really wasn't the question, but unless you operate a hosting service, I can't think of a single reason to allow users drop tables, let alone entire databases. Honestly this one sounds like an XY Problem more than anything else.

Well The reason why I asked is this: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/293996/119952

You received that answer because generally speaking, you must use prepared statements anywhere where user inputted data gets written into database. But if it's a test case and you know only you have access to it, you can use unsanitized query. Especially because the goal of prepared statements is exactly to prevent users reach a table, or database you didn't explicitly allowed them to. But honestly, I would rather just do the tests, then drop the no longer necessary databases manually after I finished. Automating it sounds like a disaster waiting to happen.

I run the tests in github action and each nest needs a clean db. Dropping the schema and re-creating is 30-40 second slower. I also try to parallelize my tests as well. I can document the user creation instead and what permissions require from db.

Furthermore the phpunit run will use a dedicated mariadb running upon a docker container as well. Therefore, I will mitigate any issues regarding test execution.

@sgtGiggsy Do you mean Just create a Unique Db with a random suffix and that's it?
So the DB user will need only the create Permission if any?

I mean I don't know what exactly your tests do with the databases, but probably it's not huge of a plus work to manually drop the databases it created after the tests are done. That's the safest way to do it, as it would prevent any script with a user entered DROP db command reach the production version of the software.
